# How to run subprograms with root permissions on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, permissions, sudo, su

With the Android SDK, I can run a process as a superuser by invoking `su` and then running my code. How can I do the same on iOS?

Here's what I use on Android:

```
// Elevate to root
Process localProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "su");

// Now run some command as root
DataOutputStream localDataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream( localProcess.getOutputStream());
localDataOutputStream.writeBytes( "chmod 666 file.name\n");
localDataOutputStream.writeBytes( "exit\n");
localDataOutputStream.flush();
```

I've tried the following C commands, but I receive an error stating that my password is incorrect.

```
system( "ls -l /System/Library/TextInput/TextInput_zh.bundle/Keyboard-zh.plist"); // read start permissions
system( "sudo -s alpine | chmod 666 /System/Library/TextInput/TextInput_zh.bundle/Keyboard-zh.plist"); // trying change permissions
system( "ls -l /System/Library/TextInput/TextInput_zh.bundle/Keyboard-zh.plist"); // read changes
```

The log looks like this:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel 7813 Dec 16 10:47 /System/Library/TextInput/TextInput_zh.bundle/Keyboard-zh.plist
>
> chmod: changing permissions of `/System/Library/TextInput/TextInput_zh.bundle/Keyboard-zh.plist': Operation not permitted
>
> We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
>   Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
>
> ```
> #1) Respect the privacy of others.
> #2) Think before you type.
> #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
> ```
>
> Password:
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel 7813 Dec 16 10:47 /System/Library/TextInput/TextInput_zh.bundle/Keyboard-zh.plist

How can I programmatically run any script with root permissions on iOS? I'm looking for an answer that will work on jailbroken devices, but would be happy with something that also works on stock devices, if that's possible.

Comment: with jailbreak: easily, without jailbreak: in no way.

Comment: @H2CO3 please any example with jailbreak, and question: in android i need install superuser application for run this code. In iOS I must install any programm before?

Comment: You have no chance to make the legal way. Apple does not such apps in the store. What also, because of security reasons, is very good. Why are viewing categories at all in such a deep level in?

Comment: @Mirko Brunner, I create In-house app without publish in the store. I need run scripts with root permissions (change files and directories, change his attributes, etc) on devices with jailbreak.

Comment: I don't understand why my question have many downvotes!!??? I don't break any rules with this question. And I think peoples with answer "with jailbreak: easily, without jailbreak: in no way" and don't give answer with examples is a big flooders.

Comment: @cpburnz, Thank you, i will trying this code apply in my app... please wait few moments for result

Answer (score 4):

One major feature of IOS is sandboxing which means that apps reside in their own file system which is not visible to other apps. What you want to do goes against the Security design of IOS.

If what you need to do is allow a set of apps to talk to one another and share data, there are ways and means to do this through shared Document types, Exported UTIs and the DocumentInteraction class,

Comment: I know few apps with sudo permissions. For example, iFile. This app can similar function like i need. What I need make to get permissions for my app like iFile?

Comment: Yes, I know about jailbreak. And I ask: How I can PROGRAMMATICALLY run script with SUDO permissions on iOS WITH jailbreak?

Answer (score 2):

Your `sudo` command is malformed:

```
sudo -s alpine | chmod 666 /System/Library/TextInput/TextInput_zh.bundle/Keyboard-zh.plist
```

Which is interpreted as:

```
sudo -s <sudo-command> | <non-sudo-command>
```

This is attempting to run the `alpine` command with `sudo`, and piping its output
to `chmod` which doesn't make sense. Since `chmod` does not get run as root, it outputs:

```
chmod: changing permissions of `/System/Library/TextInput/TextInput_zh.bundle/Keyboard-zh.plist': Operation not permitted

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

#1) Respect the privacy of others.
#2) Think before you type.
#3) With great power comes great responsibility.
```

And since `sudo` was not provided a password (the `-S` argument), it
prompts for the password by outputting:

```
Password:
```

I think you intended to do:

```
echo <password> | sudo -S <command>
```

Where I believe you intended to use `alpine` as the password which would then be:

```
echo 'alpine' | sudo -S chmod 666 /System/Library/TextInput/TextInput_zh.bundle/Keyboard-zh.plist
```

See [man(8) sudo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html) for additional information on `sudo`.

Comment: I am trying to run the below command and got some error, please tell me how to fix this

Comment: system("echo 'alpine' | sudo -S tcpdump -c 20 -i en1 -vvv -A host www.facebook.com");

Comment: Error: We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

Password:
mobile is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: @PalchuriSudheerKumar You should really post this as a new question.