# Execute the command with root privilege on jailbroken iOS devices using system function

Tags: ios, command, root, jailbreak, sudo

I searched some related questions in this forum. The most relevant Question is

> [How to run subprograms with root permissions on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676583/how-to-run-subprograms-with-root-permissions-on-ios/30369218?noredirect=1#comment48830090_30369218)

I realized, that there is a function on Android also with

> Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "su");

and now I want to realize the same function on iOS. In the process of realization. I need to get the root privilege. bucause some commands should run with root privilege.

I use the following method

> system("ping 127.0.0.1");

All is ok. But when I change the route table with

> system("route add -host 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.11");

I get the error. Because adding route item to the route table needs root privilege. I tried the following command

> echo alpine | sudo -s route add -host 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.11

but there is no sudo command.

Thanks in advance for any useful pointers/suggestions/thoughts.

Comment: I really doubt that you can reach root privilege in iOS without jailbreaking your device.

Comment: @NicolasBuquet  I have jailbreaked my ios device.I tried the application named ios terminal. that is a napplication which looks like cmd or terminal in windows/linux. using the default account and pwd can get root privilege

Answer (score 1):

You can't get root privileges on iOS. (**EDIT:** Unless you are on a jailbroken device, I guess)

But you cant take a look at [this class](https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBPing), that achieves ICMP pings.
I'm not sure about the route though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will see the code you gave me. there are some similar apps in the app store.But  I tried the application named ios terminal. that is a napplication which looks like cmd or terminal in windows/linux. using the default account and pwd can get root privilege.so there is a way to get root privilege

Comment: I think this is a fake/emulated root access. iOS will NEVER let you out of your app sandbox (excepted for public APIs that allow access to shared data (keychain, inter-app audio...)... unless you are working on jailbroken devices.

Comment: you are right. i want to get root privilege on a jailbroken ipad. now this is my problem that how to execute the command with root privilege on jailbroken ios devices using system("***") function

Comment: Then you should specify it in your question, maybe you'll get answers from jailbroken apps developers.

Comment: thanks for your warning. i will edit my question immediately.